# NextJS Docker Container in K8s Throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, docker, kubernetes, next.js, minikube

Creating a default NextJS typescript app with `npx create-next-app@latest --ts .`

```
 "next": "12.1.6",
 "react": "18.1.0",
 "react-dom": "18.1.0"
```

and then a simple Dockerfile deployed to kubernetes minikube and then minikube tunnel to access the port

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .


CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

Shows a blank page with the following errors in the console when running in browser

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

However running the same image via `docker run`, in non k8s, works fine. I have had a look at the HTML for absolute paths as suggested in other threads and see that the path points to

http://myhost.com/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1654439747173

When hovering over src

```
<div id="__next">
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1654439747173"></script>
```

deployment.yaml and ingress files

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: front-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: front
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: front
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          image: mine/front:latest
          resources:
           limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: front-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: front
  ports:
    - name: front
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000


// ingress

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: front-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Any idea on getting it running in kubernetes?

Comment: how you are exposing service in docker and k8s and checking out in browser ?  is there chance starting dev server takes time and facing `<` error in browser ? are you using ingress or anything in k8s to access service ?

Comment: If you connect to the service using, say, `curl`, what response _do_ you get back?  Does this setup work with plain Docker without Kubernetes?  With plain Node, without a container at all?  What URL are you trying to call, and how have you made it accessible from outside the cluster?  If the problem is at the Kubernetes layer, can you [edit] the question to include enough of the Kubernetes YAML manifests to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze When connecting via curl it prints the same index.html I see in chrome devtools. I have updated the question with deployment and ingress yaml

Comment: @HarshManvar Dev server doesnt appear to be taking its time. I am using ingress and I have updated the question with the ingress files

Comment: that could mean you get html back where you expect a javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by updating the ingress rewrite target

changing

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

to

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

and the path to

```
path: /(.*)
```

Comment: You dont need any rewrite here. Remove this annotation and set the path to / as prefix.

Comment: @TheFool the rewrite I'm gonna need when adding another service that is accessible via the same domain albiet a specific path e.g. myhost.com/colors, to route to '/' on that backend service

Comment: Sometimes you need to rewrite, correct. But right now, your rewrite does nothing besides degrading performance. You are rewriting /(.*) to  /$1. That's the same as having a / as prefix without any rewrite, except for it's more overhead.

Comment: Even with a second service, you can use a second ingress manifest. They can have the same host as long as the path differs.